# p:selectManyMenu filter doesn't work with itemDisabled

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My `p:selectManyMenu` has a `filter` and it works fine when I remove `itemDisabled` from `f:selectItems`.

However, when I use `itemDisabled` the filtered values are wrong.

How to solve that?

```
<p:selectManyMenu
    id="horario"
    value="#{clienteMB.horariosSelecionados}"
    converter="MultiSelectEntityConverter"
    var="t"
    filter="true"
    filterMatchMode="contains"
    showCheckbox="true">
    <f:selectItems
        itemDisabled="#{not empty consulta.datamarc}"
        value="#{clienteMB.horarioList}"
        var="consulta"
        itemLabel="#{consulta.dataHoraFormatted()}"
        itemValue="#{consulta}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{t.dataHoraFormatted()}" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Comment: Like here... no [mcve], no version info, so not really an incentive for trying to help...